# How do I let users upload files to a chosen location?

Tags: php, images, forms

I found some plugins which let me make my own forms but none worked for different reasons.

I simply want to make a form so that users can upload files to a folder located in www.chusmix.com/images

I'm trying this code, but it sends me to a "page not found":

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos">

Please specify a file:<br>
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, instead of:

```
<form method="POST" action="url">
```

Use this instead:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="url">
```

You can then fetch the resulting files using the $_FILES superglobal.

---

In WP 3.1, the whole uploads infrastructure should be available as an API unless I'm mistaking. But it won't necessarily work on the front end, let alone allow you to easily decide where the files go.

You could use parts of it to validate file types, etc., though. See the stuff in:

- wp-includes/media.php
- wp-admin/includes/media.php

Comment: Hi Denis. Look I tried this using your that code:
'<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos">

Please specify a file:<br>
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>
'
I have to put the url I wants the files to be uploaded where it says url right? I did that and changed the folder permission to be publicly modifiable with filezilla but I'm not getting them online. I still feel I'm very close... Do I need to add anything else or what?

Comment: I copied the code above so it's more clear.